# Naming Sheets in Excel through Sheet Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried this code that would get the value of a cell in the sheet:

```
lastRow = 0
lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' count the occupied cells in wb2

For i = 1 To lastRow - 1
    Sheets.Add
    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A" & i) = ActiveSheet.Name
Next i
```

But, unfortunately it is not working. Let's say:

[image]

So, in my code, I have counted the cell that is not empty. And then, I added a worksheet according to the number of counted occupied cells. While looping, I have to get the value in `A1` and set it as the name for `Sheet` and so on. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim lastRow As Integer


lastRow = 0
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' count the occupied cells in wb2

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```

I think the reason it didn't work for you is because your loop was selecting the same sheet over and over again and renaming cells within the sheet instead of the renaming the sheet as cells within the first sheet.

EDIT: Removed unnecessary print statements and take into account Marisa's good point about the -1 not being necessary in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a named sheet in a single line, with my lines in your loop like below. The `Sheets.Add` allows you to pass in the value of the name you want it to be called.

```
Dim s as String
s = Range("A" & i).value
Sheets.Add s
Sheets(1).activate
```

Comment: I'm sorry but returns an error: Method 'Add'  of 'Sheets' failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
lastRow = 0
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' count the occupied cells in wb2

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set s = Sheets.Add
    s.Name = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

Comment: It returns an error: Application-defined or Object defined Error.

Comment: Which line gives you that error?
This exact code works for me both in Excel 2007 & 2013

Comment: This one: `s.Name = Cells(i, 1).Value
`

Comment: OK I also get this error if I put the code under ThisWorkbook
If I however put it under Sheet1 then it works

Comment: There's an error because lastRow is not initialised. But then it's not initialised in the question either so we're assuming that you had it initialised earlier in your code.

Comment: Actually I was wrong; that's not the problem. I finally figured it out: the error is caused by Cells(i, 1).Value selecting a cell in the new worksheet that was just added instead of the cell in Sheet1 where all the names are being kept. In this case, it'll be trying to rename the worksheet with a null/blank string which is probably what's giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Gunnar has beaten me to posting a working answer :) But to add a little explanation, here's the answer I was writing anyway! :

From what I can see there are a couple of problems...

Firstly, you have

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

but this will always just try to activate Sheet1, and surely you want to cycle through the new pages? (otherwise always trying to rename the same sheet...)

Then to rename the sheet, you need

```
ActiveSheet.Name =
```

on the left (otherwise will be trying to set whatever is on the left of the = as the value of the sheet name)

So from this...

```
Sheet1.Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' count the occupied cells

For i = 1 To lastRow   'don't need the -1 ;)
    Sheets.Add         'new sheet will automatically be the one active I think
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm sorry but I've already tried this one and it's the same. It also returns: Application-defined or Object-defined error.